# Losing AWT DrawingSurface when Canvas is hidden

Tags: java, opengl-es, awt, rendering, jawt

I am writing 3d rendering module for an AWT/Swing application.

To provide good FPS, I can't draw using Swing/AWT methods and graphics. Instead, I obtain the Drawing Surface from the Canvas element, and then render directly to it. Something like this:

```
public class Window {

    private Component canvas;
    private JAWTDrawingSurface ds;

    public static final JAWT awt;
    static {
        awt = JAWT.calloc();
        awt.version(JAWT_VERSION_1_4);
        if (!JAWT_GetAWT(awt))
            throw new AssertionError("GetAWT failed");
    }

    public void lock() throws AWTException {
        int lock = JAWT_DrawingSurface_Lock(ds, ds.Lock());
        if ((lock & JAWT_LOCK_ERROR) != 0)
            throw new AWTException("JAWT_DrawingSurface_Lock() failed");
    }

    public void unlock() throws AWTException {
        JAWT_DrawingSurface_Unlock(ds, ds.Unlock());
    }

    public void Init2()
    {    
        this.ds = JAWT_GetDrawingSurface(canvas, awt.GetDrawingSurface());
        try
        {
            lock();
            // Create GL Capabilities
            unlock();
        }
     }
```

It works fine when I call it the first time.
But when I hide the canvas for any reason (for example minimizing window or displaying another panel instead of Canvas), the **ds** variable remains the same, but it doesn't work after that.
Basically, even if I make sure I call the variable only when it is visible and on top - any call using **ds** will throw an exception. For example **lock()** function stops working.

I'm wondering why's that?

Also I tried to basically obtain a new DS if I minimize and then maximize the window again, but this also doesn't work - the new DS address is returned as it should, but I can't use that new object just as I couldn't use the original one.

There's probably something stupid I'm missing here, but I can't figure out what.
Please help me sort this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

When the Canvas is hidden, call eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay,EGL_NO_SURFACE,EGL_NO_SURFACE,EGL_NO_CONTEXT) to unbind the current context.

When you need to start drawing again, you need to do something like this:

```
public void Reinit()
{
    System.err.println("Context Reinit()");

    this.ds = JAWT_GetDrawingSurface(canvas, awt.GetDrawingSurface());
    try
    {
        lock();
        try
        {
            JAWTDrawingSurfaceInfo dsi = JAWT_DrawingSurface_GetDrawingSurfaceInfo(ds, ds.GetDrawingSurfaceInfo());

            JAWTX11DrawingSurfaceInfo dsiWin = JAWTX11DrawingSurfaceInfo.create(dsi.platformInfo());

            this.display = dsiWin.display();
            this.drawable = dsiWin.drawable();

            eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(display);

            surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay,fbConfigs.get(0),drawable,(int[])null);

            eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay,surface,surface,context);

            GLES.setCapabilities(glesCaps);

            JAWT_DrawingSurface_FreeDrawingSurfaceInfo(dsi, ds.FreeDrawingSurfaceInfo());
        }
        finally
        {
            unlock();
            System.err.printf("Unlock \n");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("JAWT Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As You can see, I re-create the display and surface, but I use the previously created context for rendering, without needing to re-create it.